# Using endnotes AND numbering from another document

Tags: endnotes, flowfram

Can you use the endnotes generated by another document to feed the current document?

[image]

My planned workflow is to put endnotes in a `sepfootnotes` file, mark the placement of each note in `DocA.tex`, then print the content of each note in `DocB.tex`. The MWE is `DocB.tex`. I'm using `flowfram` to embed DocA as a PDF in a static frame. That allows three columns of flow frames to print very extensive notes from DocA.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\geometry{margin=0pt}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}

\makebackgroundframe

\newstaticframe*{5.497in}{7.329in}
{3.003in}{3.671in}[pagegraphic]

\newflowframe{2.493in}{9.976in}
{0.30in}{0.6in}[leftcol]

\newflowframe{2.493in}{2.780375in}
{3.003in}{0.6in}[middlecol]

\newflowframe{2.493in}{2.780375in}
{5.706in}{0.6in}[rightcol]

\newcommand{\pagebox}[1]{%
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{#1}}}

\setstaticframe{1}{backcolor={[rgb]{0.976,0.937,0.78}}}
\setstaticframe{2}{border=pagebox, offset=-2pt, backcolor={[rgb]{1, 1, 1}}}

\begin{document}

\RaggedRight

\begin{staticcontents*}{pagegraphic}
\includegraphics[page=3, scale=0.9448]{TestiPadSize.pdf}
\end{staticcontents*}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I realize I could do it manually, by just typing in a reference to each note that appears on DocA, but as the document changes, I'd prefer to use the counters from DocA to do it, so the numbering and placement would be accurate.

My first thought would be rewriting the `\newfootnotes` command from `sepfootnotes` to use DocA's `.ent` file. But I don't know enough LaTeX to accomplish that. Is that the best approach? Is there a package that already deals with this?

I read through [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417350/) which involves `reledmac`. Seemed like a lot of overhead and functionality that I don't need, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not straightforward, but not terribly hard. The basic idea is exactly as you suggested: write the "notes" from the first document to an external file, then read them into the second document.

So, deal with the first point first:

In the first document -- what you are calling DocA:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% First we need a new "write".
\newwrite\notesdoc
\immediate\openout\notesdoc=\jobname.notes
\newcounter{enotecounter}
\newcommand{\externalnote}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{enotecounter}%
  \textsuperscript{\arabic{enotecounter}}
  \protected@write\notesdoc{}{\string\extnote{\arabic{enotecounter}}{#1}{\thepage}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Here is some text.\externalnote{Here is a note. It is a long note,
and I am hoping that it will end up going over several lines.} And
here is another\externalnote{Another}

\clearpage

Here is some text on the next page\externalnote{And this is the text.}

\end{document}
```

What this does is to "write" the notes simply by making the appropriate mark and then actually placing the text in an external file "\jobname.notes". For reasons that will become apparent, we do so by writing a command into that file.

Then the second file, which has to read in that previously written file. One problem: we are going to need some facility for matching the note to the page. To do that we assume that we start at page 1 (and we expressly place the static image on that page): thereafter we look to see whether the page number for the note has "changed": if it has, we also clear the page and insert the next page of static image.

Note -- this will fail if there are any pages in DocA that do not have notes: they will simply be omitted. But we are not trying to write a package, just a solution to a particular problem!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\thispage}{1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extnote}[3]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#3}
  \if\@tempa\thispage
  \else
  \clearpage
  \begin{staticcontents*}{pagegraphic}
    \includegraphics[page=#3, scale=0.6]{200219a.pdf}
  \end{staticcontents*}
  \fi
  \par\textbf{#1}.\quad#2}
\makeatother

\geometry{margin=0pt}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}

\makebackgroundframe

\newstaticframe*{5.497in}{7.329in}
{3.003in}{3.671in}[pagegraphic]

\newflowframe{2.493in}{9.976in}
{0.30in}{0.6in}[leftcol]

\newflowframe{2.493in}{2.780375in}
{3.003in}{0.6in}[middlecol]

\newflowframe{2.493in}{2.780375in}
{5.706in}{0.6in}[rightcol]

\newcommand{\pagebox}[1]{%
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{#1}}}

\setstaticframe{1}{backcolor={[rgb]{0.976,0.937,0.78}}}
\setstaticframe{2}{border=pagebox, offset=-2pt, backcolor={[rgb]{1, 1, 1}}}

\begin{document}

\RaggedRight

\begin{staticcontents*}{pagegraphic}
\includegraphics[page=1, scale=0.6]{200219a.pdf}
\end{staticcontents*}

\input{200219a.notes}

\end{document}
```

Having placed the (first) static content page, we then simply input the notes file, which in its turn prints the notes, and changes the page and the "static" frame where necessary.

We then run DocA and then DocB.

Result:

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

As noted: this is not super-robust (nor by any means fully tested). It's going to fail tolerably if the notes go over more than one page. And it's going to fail miserably if there is a page which doesn't have notes. If you wanted to add text *as well as* notes, you could do that probably, but you'd need to write an extra command for DocA to do it. Basically, once it's all set up, everything you actually want to WRITE goes into DocA: DocB is just a sort of wrapper -- though you could perfectly well have text before or after.

**EDITED TO ADD** Incidentally, I'd say that `reledmac` is exactly right for this, and not overkill. But YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  That looks like it answers the question.  But you raise a good point about the robustness.  I’ll have to take a second look at reledmac and see if I need more of it than I thought.

Comment: I've taken a second look at `reledmac`. Because of the unbalanced space between DocA and DocB (using `flowfram`), I don't see any way to get that package to perform in the way I want. Ideally I don't want to typeset two documents simultaneously. I prefer to use one that's already typeset as input for the annotation. That said, I think your solution is closest to what I want. I've been hacking at it to make it more robust but I'm confused about some things: 1) Why use the #3 argument to include the PDF instead of \thispage? 2) Similarly shouldn't @tempa be tested against \thepage instead?

Comment: The pseudocode I've been trying is this: a) does the current note page number equal the current document page number b) if it does, print it (moving this line up into the conditional rather than after) c) if it does not, use the multido package to perform the following for each page ahead of the current one: 1) print "No Notes" if we havent printed a note on this page 2) clear the page, 3) input the next PDF, and 4) reset the notesonpage counter to zero. But I can't get TeX to realize equality between @tempa and \thepage. Am I going down the wrong path? If not, why won't that if clause work?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'd need to spend a bit of time with it. I think I found "empirically" (i.e. cargo-cult programming) that `\thispage` didn't sit well if passed into the argument to include the pdf. You don't want to test against `\thepage` I don't think (but feel free to try) because you need to coordinate it with writes out properly and page breaking. Where the code is certainly *wrong* is that when the page number does advance, we need to redefine `\thispage`, or it is going to work for the first two pages only.